# How to split values inside column filter using Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable and in this table, a specific column cell have lists of several values separated by comma, by default the entire lists of cell is used in the single filter option. But I want list of values of a cell should be split into individual filters option.

I have a datatable which look like this.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Alice</td>
            <td>England</td>
            <td>English,Swedish,French</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>German</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Third column may contain multiple values, separated by comma`(,)`.

I am using jQuery plugin Datatables to make interactive table with dropdown filter for last column.

This is my code for this:

```
initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns(3).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value="">Select All</option></select>')
            .appendTo( $('#language').empty().append('<label>Filter by Language:</label>') )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
```

I have found this [article](https://legacy.datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColumnFilterWidgets/DataTables/extras/ColumnFilterWidgets/separator.html) and using below code. Its create the filter inside the table wrapper but I want it outside of the table. here is the screenshot of my live datatable [image]

```
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready( function () {
                $('#myDatatable').dataTable( {
                    "sDom": 'W<"clear">lfrtip',
                    "oColumnFilterWidgets": {
                        "aiExclude": [ 0,1 ],
                        "sSeparator": ','
                    }
                } );
            } );
        </script>
```

Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Hi, can you create working demo code?

Comment: Hi @Swati, Here is the working demo link [https://jsfiddle.net/yajuvendra1990/m8bdcswg/16/](https://jsfiddle.net/yajuvendra1990/m8bdcswg/16/)

Comment: I tested you code if you remove this `this.api().columns(4).every( function () {..})` whole part from that fiddle then only the last dropdown will get shown .Try and see onces.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I think you did not understand my concern. I want 2nd dropdown  option value look like as 3rd dropdown option value. OR 3rd dropdown should be appended in `<span id="language"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

Working demo [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yajuvendra1990/m8bdcswg/79/)

```
this.api().columns(4).every( function () {
    var column = this;
    var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value="">Select All</option></select>')
    .appendTo( $('#language').empty().append('<label>Filter by Language:</label>') )
    .on( 'change', function () {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
            $(this).val()
        );

        column
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
    } );
    column.data().unique().sort().each( function( d, j ) {      
       var nameArr = d.split(",");
        nameArr.forEach(function(number) {                
            var optionExists = ($("#language option[value='"+number+"']").length > 0);
            if(!optionExists){
                select.append( '<option value="'+number+'">'+number+'</option>' );
            }                    
        });                     
       
    } );           
    
} );
```